# Why do Rebels have so many [Letter]-Wing Fighters?

Tags: star-wars, names

In Star Wars the bigger part of rebel fighters are named after a letter, e.g. A-, B-, X- and Y-Wings.
This pattern does not carry over to fighters of other factions. (E.g. a TIE fighter could have easily be named H-Wing, but is not).

Is there any in-universe or out-of-universe explanation for these names?

I am not looking for the answer that they are called that because they look like a letter, but rather the answer to why this type of naming exists and exists only for rebels.

Comment: Because it looks cool and being a rebel is about being cool.

Comment: Same reason USAF call their planes by type (F for fighter, B for bomber etc) while USSR/Russia calls them by production factory (MiG, SU, YAK) - different countries, different rules.

Comment: Yeah, it so totally could be named the H-Wing, but TIE stands for Twin Ion Engine.

Comment: @DataTNGlover: I know, but the X-Wings's official name is Incom Corporation T-65 (or T-70 for the new version). Still they are never called that in the movies.

Comment: @Valorum, that sounds about right^^ Would be just cool to have in interview or something that confirms that (out-of-universe explanation)

Comment: Rebels use informal names for their craft (eg. X-Wing for T-65, etc), while the Empire tend to be more bureaucratic.

Comment: I'll go you one better - they don't look like the letters from the Aurebesh alphabet. Whatever they're "really" called in their language, they don't even match the letters.

Comment: You could argue something along the lines of the Empire being bureaucratic and highly organized therefore it makes sense that they'd tend to address their vehicles with a more official name. And then on the other side, the Rebels are less organized and more prone to shortcuts and personality in their naming conventions. But that notion doesn't jive well with the Empire using the name "Death Star"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apparently, there is Latin alphabet in SW universe and it is called [High Galactic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/High_Galactic)**

Therefore X-wing (officially T-65) got his name because it resembled High Galactic letter X with S-foils opened, Y-wing (BTL-.. ) resembled Y e.t.c.

Of course, out-of-universe, at the time "New Hope" was released people could only watch movie once (or few times if they really like it) and occasionally buy comics. Therefore, it would be counterproductive to bombard them with information they could not process. So Rebels had X-wings and Y-wings (easy to remember because of shape) , Empire had Tie-fighters and that was about it. Later when SW became a success and personal computers came about it was all gradually expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they started with one fighter, and then it was quite simple to just continue to name spacecraft after fighters. People (and aliens presumably) are creatures of habit, and they do not change established systems when it is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because of both the shape resemblance to the letter (like the y wing or t wing), and also because it is is probably a type of organisational thing for the designers, and thus easier to organise in a archive system.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of the above from in universe sources?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If we're talking English, yes. But the language of Star Wars is [Arebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh), which has no symbols like that

Comment: This explains why they're named the way they are, to some degree, but it doesn't explain the in-universe association between the Rebels and this specific category of ship.